# Fail2Ban regex exclude if / found after certain point

Tags: regex, regex-negation, fail2ban

In a nutshell, I want to find all requests for php files in the root of my web app, but not in subdirectories.

E.g. I would like the following to match:

```
/home/myapp/public_html/anyfile.php
```

but not the following:

```
/home/myapp/public_html/subdir/anyfile.php
```

My regex looks like this:

```
\/home\/myapp\/public_html\/\S*(?!\/)\S*\.php
```

It's matching both examples above - I can't seem to get it to fail if there's another / after /public_html/

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems I need to use `[^\/]+` to match anything but / at that point, so the regex will be:

```
\/home\/myapp\/public_html\/[^\/]+\.php
```